# getting errors in oracle nodemanager - command 'SYNC_CHANGELIST' failed

Tags: java, oracle, forms, weblogic12c

after installing Oracle Weblogic 12.2.1.2 with Form and Reports 12.2.1.2 I see a lot of errors like this:

```
Cannot load the plugin factory oracle.forms.plugin.cam.FormsPluginFactory from the classloader. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError        
Dec 17, 2016 11:28:15 AM oracle.dms.cam.metrics.LocalDmsChannel oracle.dms.cam.metrics.LocalDmsChannel
    INFO: DMS startup class is not started. DMS runs with reduced functionality.
    <Dec 17, 2016 11:28:16 AM EET> <WARNING> <Processing for FORMS server 'forms1' failed due to: [Plugin not found for system component type 'FORMS', plugin type 'PROCESS']. Please check Node Manager log and/or server 'forms1' log for detailed information.>
    <Dec 17, 2016 1:04:20 PM EET> <WARNING> <Node Manager command 'SYNC_CHANGELIST' failed unexpectedly due to: [Plugin not found for system component type 'FORMS', plugin type 'REPLICATION']. Please check Node Manager log and/or server log for detailed information.>
```

in nodemanager log. 
And I can't start ohs, getting error:

```
Received error message from Node Manager Server: [Node Manager command 'SYNC_CHANGELIST' failed unexpectedly due to: [Plugin not found for system component type 'FORMS', plugin type 'REPLICATION']. Please check Node Manager log and/or server log for detailed information.]. Please check Node Manager log for details.
```

Wasn't able to find any information in google. Maybe someone know how to fix it?

Comment: looks like source of my problems is here: Cannot load the plugin factory oracle.forms.plugin.cam.FormsPluginFactory from the classloader. java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError